# Xamarin:Listening issue in geoLocator in IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, geolocation

I an using GeoLocator for current location in xamarin.so when i start listening it shows my current location but when i pause and again start then is shows lat=0,long=0 
only in IOS.(in Andorid everything works fine.)
This is my Code:

```
public async void CurrentLocation()
{
    try
    {
        await 
    CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 
    0, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
        {
            ActivityType = 
        Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
            AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
            DeferLocationUpdates = true,
            DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
            //DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            ListenForSignificantChanges = false,
            PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

        });
        CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += changedPosition;
    }
}

public void Start_button()
{
CurrentLocation();
}
public async void Pause_button()
{
 await CrossGeolocator.Current.StopListeningAsync();
}
```

please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Comment: not yet, i am trying.

Answer (score 1):

There may be instances where you install a plugin into a platform that it isn’t supported yet. This means you will have access to the interface, but no implementation exists. You can make a simple check before calling any API to see if it is supported on the platform where the code is running.

```
public bool IsLocationAvailable()
{
 if(!CrossGeolocator.IsSupported)
    return false;

 return CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable;
}
```

In iOS your app is required to have keys in your Info.plist for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in order to access the device’s location.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
```

> Background Updates

Only implement this and add these properites if you need background updates for your application. Most likely you will not. Adding this also has direct impact on permissions and prompts to the user. Please be very careful when adding this information.

Inside of your info.plist you must enable Background Modes/UIBackgroundModes for location updates. Here is a full guide. Your info.plist should contain something like this:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
    <string>location</string>
  </array>
```

In addition to `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` you are required to add `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` keys in your app’s Info.plist file. (If your app supports iOS 10 and earlier, the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key is also required.) If those keys are not present, authorization requests fail immediately.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open and in the background.</string>
```

For more detail you can refer [Github demo](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin)